# How do I decide the tail dimensions and the distance between the wings for a bi plane?

Tags: aircraft-design, aerodynamics, general-aviation

So I am designing a biplane,I know the weight.I want to know what is  the lift formula , volume ratio and aspect ratio for a biplane? I know the formulas for monoplane

Comment: What calculations in particular are you asking about? Are you trying to design a biplane, or to measure the wing and tail area of an existing one? Please [edit] your question with more details.

Comment: Yes sir,I am designing a new biplane. I want to know  how is the lift formula, volume ratio and aspect ratio different from the conventional one....so I know the weight of my plane ,I have to calculate the wing dimensions and tail dimensions...I know the method for conventional plane. .

Comment: You need to do a few research on the internet,there are articles on google that'll help you understand these basics....Lift formula,aspect ratio,reynolds number etc.....mostly on the net,just do your research.Goodluck man.@sai teja

Comment: So I have actually gone through the basics. So the thing is in the net I wasn't able to find any calculations for biplane,so I thought stack exchange was the place !

Comment: Hi Sai, welcome to aviation.SE. Unfortunately I feel that despite your edits your question is not really answerable as it is now. It would either require an overly long answer, or assume that you know things that you might not know. It would be better if you could focus on a specific point (for example, "given wing load factor, MTOW, and top speed, what is the formula to dimension the main wing of a biplane?") and ask other specific questions separately, this will help both you and us. You can also look here for guidance on how to ask: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Federico Thank you sir. I'm new to stack exchange and I do not know how these forums work.Thanks alot for your guidance , I really appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

They are the same, but you have to use the total area of both wings multiplied by an interference factor that will be $<1$ to represent the loss of efficiency due to interference between both wing planes.

Comment: Oh ok thank you sir!...how do I get the interference factor..  also I have edited my question.so I want to know from the design point of view how is it different from a monoplane

Comment: There is a wealth of information from existing designs.  Generally, the horizontal stabilizer needs to be large enough to counteract the nose up pitching tendency of the wing at higher angles of attack.  Also it should be of a lower aspect ratio so the wing stalls first.  Building models and flying them is hugely helpful in gaining expertise in design.  Interference between wings can be improved by putting one ahead of the other, and by increasing space between them.